# Mock instance of a private controller in another class during tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have a controller that makes a request to an API (ExampleController).

```
public class ExampleController {
     public String getDownloadURL(String a, String b, String c){
          // performs GET request
          return response;
     }
}
```

This controller is used as part of a function in another class (ExampleMemberClass).

```
 public class ExampleMemberClass() {
     private ExampleController controller = new ExampleController();

     public String getMemberDownloadURL(Object o, String c) {
        // some logic
        // generate variable b
        String responseURL = controller.getDownloadURL(a, b, c);
        // some logic
        return responseURL;
     }
 }
```

I want to create a Unit Test for ExampleMemberClass where I test the logic of getMemberDownloadURL, without running the actual getDownloadURL request. (I want to mock a response using Mockito/PowerMock instead)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my class not calling my mocked methods in unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-is-my-class-not-calling-my-mocked-methods-in-unit-test)

Comment: Welcome. In your code the controller instance is directly instantiated in the class with `new`. So, whenever you create a new ExampleMemberClass the controller is already set. For mocking as well as for a more de-coupled design,  the controller could i.e. be set via setter or constructor? Then also your mock / unit test could provide a mock instance via this mechanism.

Comment: @swinkler Thanks a lot, adding a setter to the ExampleMemberClass solved my issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is to add a couple of constructors to ExampleMemberClass, one with no arguments and one that takes a ExampleController as an arg. e.g.

```
private ExampleController controller;

public ExampleMemberClass() {
 controller = new ExampleController();
}

public ExampleMemberClass(ExampleController controller) {
 this.controller = controller;
}
```

In your `ExampleMemberClass` unit test you can use the second constructor to pass a mocked `ExampleController` that returns whatever responseURL you want.