Rewrite JMockit Mockup to Mockito: Interception of method calls of dependency api
Rewrite JMockit Mockup to Mockito: Interception of method calls of dependency api
I try to rewrite JMockit code (new Mockup) to Mockito.
In my JUnit test a method (initializeEntityManagerInterception) is called in which interceptor methods are defined. These method should intercept methods of an non explicit referenced EntityManagerImpl object which is part of a dependency API. In my JMockit test my method setId is called correctly within the interception but not in my rewritten Mockito code. So the question is: can Mockito intercept methods of not explicit dependency objects just like JMockit does ?
protected void initializeEntityManagerInterception() throws Exception {      

        new MockUp<EntityManagerImpl>() { 

            @Mock

            public void persist(Invocation i, Object o) {

                setId(o); // my own written method

                i.proceed(o);

            }
 

            @Mock

            public Object merge(Invocation i, Object o) {

                setId(o);

                return i.proceed(o);

            }

        };

    }

I tried the following mockito code but while debugging the method setId is never called:
protected void initializeEntityManagerInterception() throws Exception {
        

        EntityManagerImpl entityManagerImpl = mock(EntityManagerImpl.class);
 

        Answer<Void> persist = new Answer<Void>() {

            public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

                Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();

                Object obj = arguments[0];

                setId(obj);

                invocation.callRealMethod();

                return null;
            }

        };      

        doAnswer(persist).when(entityManagerImpl).persist(any(Object.class));       

        

        Answer<Object> merge = new Answer<Object>() {

            public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

                Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();

                Object obj = arguments[0];

                setId(obj);

                return invocation.callRealMethod();
            }

        };     

        doAnswer(merge).when(entityManagerImpl).merge(any(Object.class));
}

Adding some info: My Junit test class is subclass of a super class "BaseTest" in which method initializeEntityManagerInterception is defined.
SUT is called in myTestMethod. My Class under test runs within a local jetty deployment (Apache camel route). And that's the point: With JMockit it works perfectly without explicitly injecting Mock to SUT. The Mockup definition in initializeEntityManagerInterception() was enough. Using Mockito I tried to bring in a EntityManagerImpl-Mock like in example below.
public class MyTest extends BaseTest {
    private static final String BODY_PARAM = "body";

    @InjectMocks
    private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest; 

    private EntityManagerImpl entityManagerImpl;

    // 1. approach of mocking 
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)    
    private Exchange exchange;
 

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() throws Exception {
        super.before();       

        // 2. approach of mocking
        entityManagerImpl = mock(EntityManagerImpl.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        ...
    }
 

    @Test
    public void myTestMethod() throws Exception {      
        ...
        // call of class under test
        classUnderTest.process(exchange);
    
        ...
        Assertions.assertNotNull(params.get(BODY_PARAM));
    }
}

...
public class ClassUnderTest implements Processor {

    @Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = null;
    EntityManager entityManager = null; 

    try {
        entityManagerFactory = exchange.getContext().getRegistry().lookupByNameAndType("entityManagerFactory", EntityManagerFactory.class);
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        ...   
        entityManager.persist(someObject);
        ...
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(someOtherObject);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ...
    }
    finally {
        closeEntityManager(entityManager);
    }
  }
}


Where do you call your SUT, where does your SUT call your mock, and how do you inject the mock to your SUT?

I added some info, see above

Why do you mix annotation-based mock initialization (@Mock, @InjectMocks, MockitoAnnotations.openMocks) and manual creation of mocks and assignment (mock(EntityManagerImpl.class))? "where does your SUT call your mock, and how do you inject the mock to your SUT?" Please show the code of your SUT, how it receives the dependency, and how it calls it.

Sorry, I added comments in code, I didn't mixed the mock variations, I used them after another. It was just to show my approaches. For Mockito approach for injecting mock in SUT I used annotation @InjectMocks in class MyTest.

exchange.getContext().getRegistry().lookupByNameAndType("entityManagerFactory", EntityManagerFactory.class); returns a new EntityManagerFactory mock object instance (@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)), which will then return another new mock (still a mock with RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS). It does not return your mocked EntityManagerImpl – and how would it, it doesn't know about it and you haven't stubbed the method calls.

This is basically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test, but a lot less hidden. I don't know where you call initializeEntityManagerInterception in your test (you are not showing it), but there you create yet another mock instance. Please read the linked question and answer, it should cover your problem.

Could be related/helpful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729202/mockito-when-thenreturn-returns-always-null/74731966#74731966

Thanks @knittl, I will check the other threads.

Hm, I think I need something like    PowerMockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
Object obj = arguments[0];
setId(obj);
invocation.callRealMethod();
return null;
}
}).when(EntityManagerImpl.class, "persist", any());     to always intercept when a certain method of a dependency class is called without having a explicit mock reference

You should be able to stub all nested/chained calls of the exchange to return the correct mock instance. It's not pretty and lots of boilerplate, but it works. Maybe there's even an existing test implementation that you can use without mocking 5 chained calls.
