# Why does my test fail when migrating from mockito-all to mockito-core?

Tags: java, mockito

I am migrating from mockito-all:1.9.5 to mockito-core:2.28.2, and some of the tests that were passing are now failing.

For example, this test :

```
@ExtendWith(CdiUnitExtension.class)
@AdditionalClasses({
    XmlMockUnmarshaller.class
})
public class FeaturesTest

    @Produces
    @Mock
    private RefService refService;
    
    @Produces
    @Mock
    private PaymentService paymentService;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        this.cacheData = new CacheData();
        this.cacheData.setDateExecution("12/12/2015");
        when(refService.isDateAvailable(anyString()).thenReturn(true);
    }
    
    @Test
    public void shouldReturnErrorIfReasonHasInvalidChars() {
        // Given
        this.cacheData.setReason("qhsdlq$98%èd");
    
        // When
        List<Error> errors = paymentService.validatePayment(this.cacheData);
    
        // Then
        assertTrue(errors.size() == 1); // test fails : errors.size() = 2;
        assertEquals(errors.get(0).getField(), "reason");
    }
}
```

with the method `validatePayment` being like :

```
@Inject
RefService refService;
...
public List<Error> validatePayment(CacheData cacheData) {
    ...
    if (!refService.isDateAvailable(cacheData.getExecutionDate())) {
        errors.add(new Error("executionDate"));
    }
    ...
    return errors;
}
```

With mockito-core, this test fails because there are 2 errors in the list, as if the configuration of the mock in the `setUp` is ignored.

How can I rewrite my test to make it pass ?

Comment: You never pass your `refService` into your `paymentService` (at least you are not showing that part of the code). [Why is my class not calling my mocked methods in unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968) could be useful

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code to show how refService is injected into paymentService

Comment: Can you check if `paymentService.refService` and `test.refService` are the same instance? You can check with a debugger or `System.out.println`+`System.identityHash`. What are the memory addresses of both fields?

Comment: Yes, they are the same instance, both `refService` share the same identityHash

Comment: Next question (I haven't noticed this earlier, sorry): What is the return type of `getExecutionDate()`? Is it really a string? Because your mock is set up to only react on string parameters, not any other types. Since the getter ends in `Date`, are you sure it returns a string and not a `java.util.Date` or `java.time.Instant`?

Comment: the return type of `getExecutionDate()` is really a String

Comment: If you set a breakpoint where `isDateAvailable` is called and then execute it with the debugger, is it false or true? And is the string `null` or an actual string literal? `anyString()` will NOT match nulls.

Comment: `isDateAvailable(cacheData.getExecutionDate())` evaluates to `false` when debugging, and the string is an actual string literal (I omitted its setting in cacheData in the setup method because I didn't think it was relevant, I've added it)

Comment: Asked differently, what is the value of `new CacheData().getExecutionDate()`? I bet it is `null`

Comment: Can you share the test class definition and its annotations? Also, what version of JUnit are you using for the test?

Comment: @knittl : I mean, I omitted `this.cacheData.setDateExecution("12/12/2015");` in the question, it was always there in my code

Comment: @Mureinik : I am using junit-jupiter-api:5.9.1

Comment: @l0r3nz4cc10 you could also try changing `thenReturn` to `thenAnswer` and setting a breakpoint in the lambda to see if it is being executed. `false` means that the configured return is not being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the MockitoExtension (which for you case should be provided by the [`org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:2.28.2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/2.28.2) dependency needed for Mockito to handle the `@Mock` annotations:

```java
@ExtendWith({MockitoExtension.class, CdiUnitExtension.class})
// Here -----^
@AdditionalClasses({
    XmlMockUnmarshaller.class
})
public class FeaturesTest
```

Comment: But if the mockito extension is missing, the field should never be set at all to a mock? According to the comments, the field is already set.