# There were zero interactions with this mock when run tests together

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm getting the following error when run my tests together. If I run each test there is no issue.

```bash
Wanted but not invoked:
logger.error("Error message 2");
-> at acme.logger.MyCoreLogTest.errorWith(MyCoreLogTest.java:74)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

**MyCoreLogger**:

```java
package acme.mycore.logger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyCoreLog {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyCoreLog");
    
    public static final String id = "my_id";
    
    public static void error(String message) {
        if (System.getenv(id) != null)
            logger.error(String.format("%s, %s=%s", message, id, System.getenv(id)));
        else
            logger.error(message);
    }
}
```

**CoreLogTest**:

```java
package acme.mycore.logger;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


class CoreLogTest {
    MockedStatic<LogManager> logManager;
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        logManager = mockStatic(LogManager.class);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        logManager.close();
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void error() {
        String errorMessage = "error message";

        Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
        logManager.when(() -> LogManager.getLogger("MyCoreLog")).thenReturn(logger);

        MyCoreLog.error(errorMessage);

        verify(logger).error(errorMessage); // Ok
    }
    
    @Test
    void errorWith() {
        String errorMessage = "error message 2";

        Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
        logManager.when(() -> LogManager.getLogger("MyCoreLog")).thenReturn(logger);

        MyCoreLog.error(errorMessage);

        verify(logger).error(errorMessage);  // Wanted but not invoked: logger.error("error message 2"); Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("MyCoreLog");
```

is executed and assigned *only once*, when your `MyCoreLog` class is initially loaded (on first access).

So in the first test "logger(1)" is assigned to the static field `MyCoreLog#logger`. The second test creates a new instance "logger(2)" which is never assigned to your static field (because static field initializers are executed *once exactly*).
When executing the second test, your `MyCoreLog` still holds a reference to the logger from the first test.

This is another spin on [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968) albeit a bit more tricky to detect. You should be able to verify by using a debugger and checking and comparing the object identity of the `logger` instances in both tests and in your class.

How to solve?

1. Create only a single mock of "logger" and assign it in a `@BeforeClass` method or when loading your test class, then use this reference in `verify`
2. Get rid of the mocks and verify call altogether. Use reflection or your logging framework's facilities to query the list of active loggers and then perform the check on this logger instance.

Example code for solution 1:

```
class CoreLogTest {
    MockedStatic<LogManager> logManager;
    // only a single shared instance (the static keyword is important):
    private static final Logger loggerMock = mock(Logger.class);

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp()
    {
        logManager = mockStatic(LogManager.class);
        // LogManager.getLogger is still only executed by the first test!
        logManager.when(() -> LogManager.getLogger("MyCoreLog")).thenReturn(logger);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws Exception
    {
        logManager.close();
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void error() {
        String errorMessage = "error message";

        MyCoreLog.error(errorMessage);

        verify(logger).error(errorMessage); // Ok
    }
    
    @Test
    void errorWith() {
        String errorMessage = "error message 2";

        MyCoreLog.error(errorMessage);

        verify(logger).error(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but unfortunately didn't work, however I think you reasoning is correct. At the end I pass `logger` as a parameter for my `error` method and works as expected. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel what does "didn't work" mean exactly? Still no calls? Did you verify if the verified instance is the instance from your service?

Comment: Indeed the verified instances are not the same. I see that in the `@BeforeEach` the `logger` instance is recreate even thought is marked as final.

Comment: @GabrielMuñumel which logger instance in `@BeforeEach`? The logger instance is only created once in the fielde initializer. There cannot exist multiple instances of the `Logger loggerMock` field.

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution as posted by @knittl, with one small adjustment (adding static):

```
private static final Logger loggerMock = mock(Logger.class);
```

ps: couldn't add this as comment, due to low reputation

Comment: Ahh, very good point, yes! Without `static`, each test method would get a new instance again (JUnit creates a new instance of the class for every test method). I have fixed my answer too, to be correct. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I solved this was:

```java
class CoreLogTest {
    private static MockedStatic<LogManager> logManager;
    // only a single shared instance:
    private static final Logger loggerMock = mock(Logger.class);

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp()
    {
        logManager = mockStatic(LogManager.class);
        // LogManager.getLogger is still only executed by the first test!
        logManager.when(() -> LogManager.getLogger("MyCoreLog")).thenReturn(loggerMock);
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown()
    {
        logManager.close();
    }
    
    
    @Test
    void error() {
        String errorMessage = "error message";

        MyCoreLog.error(errorMessage);

        verify(logger).error(errorMessage); // Ok
    }
    
    @Test
    void errorWith() {
        String errorMessage = "error message 2";

        MyCoreLog.error(errorMessage);

        verify(logger).error(errorMessage);
    }
}
```