# Junit test case for Rest template in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-boot-test

I am using RestTemplate in a Spring project.Due to some reason i have created a RestTemplate Object inside a method.
Example :

```
public class Post {

    public Post(){
    }

    public T postRequest(Object request){
        // Creating a Header Part
        // Creating a Restemplate instance
        RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<T> response = rest.exchange(......)
    }
}
```

My Question : How can we write Junit Test case for postRequest method even with mock. Because i can not autowired RestTemplate in PostTest class.
Any Idea can help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you want to test? That  RestTemplate works? Or that it is called correctly?

Comment: Also why is your class named `Post` but the constructors name is `Test` and that is empty?? Please try to fix your example so that it compiles at least

Comment: @cyberbrain That is just an example , I want to know how can i mock RestTemplate Exchange method when restemplate is defined inside a method rather than autowire in a class. Thanks

Comment: Don't do it that way. Inject a `RestTemplate`, or a factory for `RestTemplate`s.

Comment: Do you have the same employer as this person?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76609702/i-am-unable-to-mock-the-resttemplate-class-in-junit-testing-spring-boot?noredirect=1#comment135072489_76609702

Comment: This question and its answer contain many possible solutions to this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test