# How to write jUnit Test Case to clear the Hashmap android

Tags: android, junit, mockito

I have a class A defined like this.

```
Class A{
Map<String, Object> someList = new HashMap<>();

void clearList(){
somelist.clear()
}

}
```

Now i need to write the test case to cover this.So i followed following approach.

```
Map<String, Object> someList;

setUp(){
someList = mock(HashMap.class)
}

@Test
testClearList(){
verify(somelist).clear();
}
```

But it gives error:

Wanted but not invoked:
hashMap.clear();
-> at java.base/java.util.HashMap.clear(HashMap.java:856)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Also i tried adding values to test hashmap , still it gives error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) – your mock and your class are 100% unrelated (the class doesn't know about the mock)

Comment: Mostly a bad idea to create mocks for collection or map instances. Why can't you put items in the map, call your clear method (`clearList` which clears a … map?!?), then assert that your map is empty. With the posted code, nothing is written to nor read from the map, so the class is basically useless