# Junit local object mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock my local object in JUnit using Mockito but it is not working.

**Original method:**

```java
Public void method1() {
    Myclass obj = new Myclass ();
    Boolean r = Obj.getData(String s1,String s2);
}
```

**Test method:**

```java
@Test
public void testcase() {
    Myclass obj1 = Mockito.mock(Myclass.class);
    Mockito.when(obj1.getData("test","test")).thenreturn(false);
}
```

But this mock is not working.

Kindly help to fix this.

Comment: Are you trying to mock the instance created inside `method1()`? This one - `Myclass obj = new Myclass ();`?

Comment: @Chaosfire yes using that mock object I need to mock the getData method

Comment: you can't mock that, obviously. it is instantiated while running the code

Comment: @Stultuske he can mock the construction, junit supports this since 3.something (not sure which minor version exactly).

Comment: hadn't seen that work yet, should try it once

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test)

Comment: Ehm, does the linked question really answer this one? All the solutions require refactoring, while mockito provides exactly the needed functionality.

Comment: @Chaosfire I would think it does. The non-working code is exactly the same as in the linked question (an independent mock that's not used anywhere in the class; and a class that creates its own instances). Yes, Mockito offers such functionality, but it does not allow finer-grained control. Throwing heavyweight frameworks at such problems can work, but it's better to understand why something does not work. By refactoring you will end up with a more flexible solution that can be tested, even without reflection or "magic".

Answer (score 2):

The instance of `Myclass` you want mocked is local to the method, meaning that even if you create the mock normally, you can't give it to the tested class to use.

What you can do, is mock the construction of objects of particular class. This means that **every** object created with `new` will be a mock - even the local variable `obj` in `method1()` will be a mock when created. Mockito supports this since [`v3.5.0`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.5.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mocked_construction).

```
@Test
public void testcase() {
  try (MockedConstruction<Myclass> ignore = Mockito.mockConstruction(Myclass.class, (mock, context) -> Mockito.when(mock.getData("test", "test")).thenReturn(false))) {
    //go on with actual test for method1()
  }
}
```

Note how the created `MockedConstruction` object is used together with `try-with-resources`. This is important, because if it's not closed the mocked construction will persist in every test you run. It can also be closed manually, if you are using `@Before`/`@After` methods for setup/cleanup.

Comment: Well, I learned something new and interesting today.  But I don't like it!  Similar to PowerMock, this makes it too easy to reach inside the implementation.  It feels icky!

Comment: It's not JUnit at play here, but Mockito. Even your link points to the Mockito JavaDoc.

Comment: @knittl Thanks for noticing the blunder, typing without thinking...