# Java Unit Test : Mock local variable to get another result

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, controller, mocking

I have controller to request some data with service layer that handle the parameter before request to server. In my controller I have object that initialize as local variable inside method. and I want to create unit test for specific condition. In my case I want to test inside BaseException block

Class that would be initiate inside method

```
class Context {
 Integer Id;
}
```

```
public ResponseEntity getApi(Parameter : param){
  Context context = new Context(param.getId())

   try {
           // request data 
            service.getData(context);

           // mapping data to show as response API
            ResponseAPI response = mapper.constructResponse(context);

            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        } catch (BaseException e) {
            // I want to testing this block
            handleBaseException(context, logContext, e);
            ResponseAPI response = mapper.constructResponse(context);

            // service will define context.getHttpStatus() based on exception inside service layer.
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.valueOf(context.getHttpStatus()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            DeliverSubscriptionMTResponse response = subscriptionMTMapper.constructResponse(context);
            HttpStatus httpStatus = HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE;
          
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, httpStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
....
doThrow(new HttpException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, "Key", "{1}", "{0}", new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE)))
.when(service)
.request(any(Context.class));

MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
.post("/your-endpoint")
.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.content(requestBody);
.....
```

but my requestBuilder will return Http Success because I send the valid requestBody.

is it possible to mock Context so I can directly handle the code inside  BaseException without re-arrange my requestBody? because I'm not sure which parameter should I modify so my controller will run the BaseException block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Junit local object mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244246/junit-local-object-mock)