# Issues when testing java code with JUnit5 and Mockito

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

I have started learning JUnit5 and Mockito and I am facing an issue when performing a unit test. I have created a small project to read an excel file. In the class which is under test here, I am grabing each file present in a folder and then sending it to another class to read the content (ReadingExcelFile).

When I am calling the method readingAllFiles in the test, it throws a nullPointerException. I don't understand the error.

**Here is the SUT:**

```
public class ExcelProcessor {

    private List<File> xlsFiles;

    public ExcelProcessor(List<File> xlsFiles) {
        if(xlsFiles == null){
            throw new NullPointerException("The array is empty");
        }

        this.xlsFiles = xlsFiles;
    }

    public void readingAllFiles()  {

        for(File xlsFile : xlsFiles){
            ReadingXlsFile excelReader = new ReadingXlsFile(xlsFile);
            excelReader.readExcelFile();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the test :**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ExcelProcessorTest {

    private ExcelProcessor processor;
    private List<File> filesList;

    @Mock
    private ReadingXlsFile excelReaderMock;

    @Mock
    private File mockFile1;

    @Mock
    private File mockFile2;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        filesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Test
    void testReadingAllFiles_whenListExists() {

        filesList.add(mockFile1);
        filesList.add(mockFile2);

        doNothing().when(excelReaderMock).readExcelFile();

        processor = new ExcelProcessor(filesList);

        // Call the method to be tested
        processor.readingAllFiles();

        // Verify that readExcelFile() is called for each file in the list
        verify(excelReaderMock, times(filesList.size())).readExcelFile();

    }
}
```

here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:149)
    at com.thomasmelchers.processor.ReadingXlsFile.readExcelFile(ReadingXlsFile.java:26)
    at com.thomasmelchers.processor.ExcelProcessor.readingAllFiles(ExcelProcessor.java:26)
    at com.thomasmelchers.processor.ExcelProcessorTest.testReadingAllFiles_whenListExists(ExcelProcessorTest.java:60)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

Comment: `excelReaderMock` is a mock, but `readingAllFiles()` uses a real instance, not the mock (it's a local variable). Read [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) and [Junit local object mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244246/junit-local-object-mock).

Comment: At first, please add stacktrace to this question which helps to investigate the relevant issue. After that think about that why do you really need to mock a file. Finally, this test is a [bikeshedding problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality). You really made a test for a JDK's for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) (your SUT is not using your mock instance in any way)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your approach.

1. As @Chaosfire correctly points out, your **SUT** is instantiating a new `ReadingXlsFile`in the `readingAllFiles` method, meaning that it will never use your mock.
   You'll likely want to either have the mock in your `ExcelProcessor` class, or use a factory for instantiating new instances, which you can then control in your unit test.
2. `doNothing().when(excelReaderMock).readExcelFile();` is missing the input parameter. You'll want to either use an `any()` derivative (I don't recommend it), or setup behaviour for each expected input.
3. Verify

   ```
   // Verify that readExcelFile() is called for each file in the list
      verify(excelReaderMock, times(filesList.size())).readExcelFile();`
   ```

   You're not actually verifying that the files are passed, only that the     amount of times it's called is equivalent to the amount of expected     files.
   The test will be arguably more correct based on your comment, if you     verify for each expected file.