# I want to mock a method which will call the external api in junit5 using mockito framework

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, junit5, wiremock

I am not able to stub the response for restTemplate.exchange(apiurl,HttpMethod.get,httpEntity,new PrametrizedTypeReference<<>>){});

```
public static List<TapDetailPojo> getTapPostList(HttpServletRequest request,String apiUrl, String xApiKey,HttpServletResponse response) {
    //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    //String idToken = (String) session.getAttribute("cognitoIdToken");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("x-api-key",xApiKey);
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    //httpHeaders.set("authorization", "Bearer " + idToken);
    List<TapDetailPojo> list = null;
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(httpHeaders);
    try {
        ResponseEntity<List<TapDetailPojo>> entityResult = restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<TapDetailPojo>>() {
                });
     
      
        list = entityResult.getBody();
    
    }catch (HttpClientErrorException exe){
      printInputPojo(httpEntity, "Error", apiUrl);
    }catch(Exception e){
      printInputPojo(httpEntity, "Error", apiUrl);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

the above is my code

I want to stub the method when api is getting called but getting the value as null

Comment: How are you stubbing? How do you define and inject your test doubles? `new RestTemplate()` creates a new, non-stubbed instance – you have to design your classes to be testable

Comment: It's best to follow knittl's advice and refactor (the code seems easy enough to refactor). You can also mock local objects with mocked object creation - [Junit local object mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77244246/junit-local-object-mock), but refactoring is better.

Comment: @Chaosfire thanks for your valuable input.
I tried with the mockConstruction and it worked perfectly fine.
Also checking with alternate methods like to mock the external endpoint using wireMock
 also taking your feedback in consideration.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following code

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
@Test
void test_RestTempate() {

ResponseEntity<Class> dummyResponse = new ResponseEntity<>(MockResponse, HttpStatus.OK);

when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.POST), Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.<Class<?>>any()).thenReturn(dummyResponse);
}
```

Comment: Not going to work, restTemplate is a local variable, the method will not magically become aware of the configured mock and use it.

Comment: @devranta I tried it as chaosfire told it will not stub the response.