# How to ignore a method being actually getting called in junit mocking

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public class DBLayer{

    public Calendar getUpdateDate(long id){
        //database logic
        return date;
    }
}


public class Service{
    private DBLayer dbLayer = new DBLayer();

    public int methodA(){
        Calendar updateDate = dbLayer.getUpdateDate(101L);
        //some logic
    }

}
```

I want to write junit test for Service class methodA but don't want getUpdateDate to be called. By spying it or mocking it, this getUpdate is also getting called.

I tried suggestion of using spy with Mockito.doReturn(), but then also getUpdateDate was getting called. How can I just ignore that being called at all.
Or should I use any other framwork (except PowerMock) to get this feature, where it can treat this DBLayer class as blackBox and ignore method being called actually.

Comment: Your class provides no possibility to inject mocks, only real classes are used. So you cannot have used `doReturn` on this method, because you do not have access to the object instance from the outside, thus it cannot have been a mock object. You probably tried to do it like described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test – the answers suggest how to restructure your code to allow testing.

Comment: You need to tell the `Service` class what `DBLayer` you are using. As written you are not allowing the Service to replace the DBLayer. One idea is to add a constructor to Service to specify the (mock) DBLayer instance.

Answer (score 0):

The method getUpdateDate() is part of your service method.

You can not test a method X and define your test like "oh I want to test X, and X executes A, but I just ignore A".

If you want to test your service method, you must either test getUpdateDate() too, OR mock getUpdateDate(), so that it returns a defined value.