# Mockito replaced already mocked objects with new ones after calling openMocks for InjectMocks annotated object

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito, guice

I have this weird situation that Mockito is replacing already mocked objects with new ones after calling `openMocks()` for `@InjectMocks` annotated object.

Here is my setup:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) public class MyTest {
    @Mock ClassA mockClassA;
    @Mock ClassB mockClassB;
    @InjectMocks ClassToTest classToTest;
    AutoCloseable closeable;
    @Before public void openMocks() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }
    //...
}

public class ClassToTest {
    @Inject private ClassA classA;
    private final ClassB classB;
    @Inject public ClassToTest(ClassB classB) {
        this.classB = classB;
    }
}
```

P.S. I don't have control over `ClassToTest`, I can't rewrite it to move the private member `classA` to the constructor.

Here I want to mock both `classA` and `classB`, while the test is for `ClassToTest`. Since `classA` is not set via constructor, I need to use `@InjectMocks` for Mockito to set it for me. And it did set it correctly with `mockClassA` I have in the test.

However, the problem is with `classB`. I set a breakpoint before `openMocks()`, there I could see `classToTest.classA` = `null` and `classToTest.classB` = `mockClassB`, which is expected. Then after calling `openMocks()`, I could see `classToTest.classA` = `mockClassA`, which is nice. But `classToTest.classB` now becomes a new mock object not `mockClassB` anymore. Since I need to setup the mock returns for `mockClassB`, replacing it with a new mock is not going to work.

Is there a way to tell Mockito not to swap `classB` with a new mock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` should already initialize all `@Mock`-and `@InjectMocks`-annotated fields.

`MockitoAnnotations.openMocks` is only required if you do not use the annotation and must manually initialize the fields.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Mock ClassA mockClassA;
    @Mock ClassB mockClassB;
    @InjectMocks ClassToTest classToTest;
    @Before public void setup() {
        when(mockClassB.someCall()).thenReturn(whatever);
    }

    @Test public void test() {
        // use this.classToTest
    }
}
```

It might be possible to do it without the `@Mock` annotations by assigning the fields directly:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyTest {
    ClassA mockClassA = mock(ClassA.class);
    ClassB mockClassB = mock(ClassB.class);
    @InjectMocks ClassToTest classToTest;
    @Before public void setup() {
        when(mockClassB.someCall()).thenReturn(whatever);
    }

    @Test public void test() {
        // use this.classToTest
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyTest {
    ClassA mockClassA = mock(ClassA.class);
    ClassB mockClassB = mock(ClassB.class);
    @InjectMocks ClassToTest classToTest;
    AutoCloseable closeable;
    @Before public void setup() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        when(mockClassB.someCall()).thenReturn(whatever);
    }

    @Test public void test() {
        // use this.classToTest
    }
}
```

Alternatively, create all mock objects manually and use reflection to assign the fields of your class under test.

Of course it always pays off to design your classes to be testable, which means that their dependencies are passed via the constructor.

This is similar to [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) (distinct references to two distinct mock objects, with your test referencing one and your class referencing a different one).

Comment: Thanks knittl, I can confirm what you said about the `MockitoJUnitRunner` sets up the mocks already is true. However, it does not assign `classA` for me (even though `classToTest` is created), thats why I needed that extra `openMocks()`. Seems the question can be "how to tell Mockito to also assign `classA` by the `MockitoJUnitRunner`?

Comment: @user1589188 What is `classA` (`mockClassA`)? It should be created and assigned by Mockito. Is it a class or an interface? You generally shouldn't mock classes. Does it have a public constructor? (It's weird that `openMocks` would create it, but the annotation does not – I'd expect the annotation to perform the same method call behind the scenes)

Comment: @user1589188 find the updated answer, maybe that's helpful. Without seeing `ClassA` and `ClassB`, it's difficult to given an answer. It might also be worthwhile to migrate to JUnit 5, as JUnit 4 is already outdated.

Comment: Thank you! That `mock()` without using annotation worked!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @knittl's idea, I ended up with this refined solution:

```
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) no need
public class MyTest {
    @Mock ClassA mockClassA;
    ClassB mockClassB = mock(ClassB.class);
    @InjectMocks ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(mockClassB);
    AutoCloseable closeable;
    @Before public void openMocks() {
        closeable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }
    //...
}
```