# Mock WebClient for JUnit

Tags: junit, mockito, webclient

How can I mock web client in JUnit test case so that I can test the following method that uses web client?

```java
public class Service {
    
    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    public Flux<String> callExternal(Request request) throws Exception {

    return webClient.post()
        .uri(externalAPIUrl)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(Mono.just(util.convertRequest(request)), ExpectedRequest.class)
        .headers(headers -> headers.add("token",util.getToken()))
        .retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class);
    }
}
```

What I have tried:

```java
 public class ServiceTest { 
         
    @Mock
    private WebClient webClient; 
   
    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }      

    @Test
    public void testCallExternal() throws Exception {

       MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

       Request request = Request.builder().id("1").build();
       Flux<String> result = Flux.just("test");   
      
       WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec.class);
       WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpec = mock(WebClient.RequestBodySpec.class);
       WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);
       WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);  
        
       String externalURL = "external url";

       when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpec);
       when(requestBodyUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
       when(requestBodySpec.contentType(any())).thenReturn(requestBodySpec);
       when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
       when(responseSpec.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpec);
       when(responseSpec.bodyToFlux(String.class)).thenReturn(result); 
       
       Flux<String> serviceResponse = Service.callExternal(request);

       assertThat(serviceResponse != null);
    }
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception from web client on the first line at webClient.post() of callExternal() which is in the service class.

Comment: Can you add what you have tried? Or resources you have used?

Comment: Sure updated now, thanks.

Comment: How do you pass  `webClientMock` to `Service` (to my eyes, you are not). How ary wou initializing `webClient` in your service?

Comment: I have updated post, hopefully it's more clear

Comment: Why are you initing your mocks twice? (initMocks and openMocks)

Comment: See section "(Mis-)using @InjectMocks" of https://stackoverflow.com/a/74027325/112968 – the root cause is the same: you are reassigning the fields holding your mock instances (`initMocks` and `openMocks` both create new mock objects and assign them to the fields)