# Mockito thenReturn(optionalEntity)-> optionalEntity.get() returns java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

Asking for why my optionalEntity.get() is returning NoSuchElementException error.

OrderItemServiceImpl

```
public OrderItem createOrderItem(OrderItemRequestDto orderItemRequestDto) {
    Optional<Order> optionalOrder = orderRepository.findOrderByUuid(orderItemRequestDto.getOrderId());

    Order order = optionalOrder.get();

    return orderItemRepository.save(orderItemRequestDto);
}
```

OrderItemServiceImplUnitTest

```
private static final UUID uuid1 = UUID.randomUUID();
private static final Order order1 = Order.builder().uuid(UUID.randomUUID()).buyer("order1").build();

@Mock
OrderItemRepository orderItemRepository;

@Mock
OrderRepository orderRepository;

public OrderItem setOrderItem1() {
        return OrderItem
                .builder()
                .uuid(uuid1)
                .build();
}

public Order setOrder() {
        return Order.builder()
                .uuid(UUID.randomUUID())
                .buyer("order1")
                .build();
}

private OrderItemRequestDto setOrderItemRequestDto3() {
    return OrderItemRequestDto
            .builder()
            .orderId(order3.getUuid())
            .itemId(item3.getUuid())
            .qty(1)
            .build();
}

@Test
public void OrderItemServiceImplTest_createOrderItem() {
        OrderItem orderItem1 = setOrderItem1();

        Optional<Order> optionalOrder = Optional.of(order1);

        logger.info("optionalOrder.get() {}", optionalOrder.get()); // log to check if optionalOrder.get() returns Order1. Log did write the Order1 with uuid and name.

        Mockito.when(orderRepository.findOrderByUuid(order1.getUuid()))
                .thenReturn(optionalOrder); // error java.util.NoSuchElementException

        orderItemServiceImpl.createOrderItem(orderItemRequestDto1);
        Mockito.verify(orderItemRepository, Mockito.times(1)).save(orderItem1);
        ArgumentCaptor<OrderItem> orderItemArgumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(OrderItem.class);

        ... // assertions
}
```

What I understood: I am mocking the `Mockito.when(orderRepository...).thenReturn(optionalOrder)` method where I am expecting it to return `optionalOrder`. Now inside the `createOrderItem` running the `optional.get()` should return a valid mocked `Order` but I am getting null.

Note: Order and OrderItem has a relationship: OrderItem.order_id

Comment: Show how do you create orderrepository mock, and better the whole test

Comment: How do you create/initialize the `orderRepository` mock instance and how do you inject it into the service? Probably one of the reasons explained in [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968)

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov, knittl I thought I added the mocked repository when I pasted the code. I deleted unnecessary code before I submitted my question. Must had removed it too by accident.

Comment: @knittl just mention since I cant mention more than 1 per comment

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth your test isn't testing any production code (except `OrderItem` and `Order`). Both service and repository are mock objects. So calling `orderItemServiceImpl.createOrderItem` never does anything, becaue `orderItemServiceImpl` is a mock. Since you want to test the behavior of your real `OrderItemServiceImpl` class, it _must not_ be mocked!. (Also note the confusing names of `setOrderItem1`, `setOrder`, and `setOrderItemRequestDto3`: they don't set anything, but are factory methods and why are some postfixed with a number?)

Comment: @knittl.  understand that I am mocking only. That is why when I execute `Mockito.when()` it should return a mocked `optionalOrder` where I can then assert later. But I am getting null instead of a mocked `optionalOrder`

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth `orderItemServiceImpl.createOrderItem` does NOT call your service's method, it calls the (empty) method on the mock object. The mock object does not care about the method implementation of the production code.