# How to mock calls to inherited methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5, java-17

I have a method that I want to test. I don't get the mocking to work.

The method looks like this:

```
public TypeA collectData(Connection dbCon, String id){
   TypeA a = new TypeA();
   a.setTime(LocalDateTime.now());
   a.setId(id);
   
   DataB dataB = new DataB(dbCon);
   TypeB b = dataB.getData(id);
   a.setB(b);

   DataC dataC = new DataC(dbCon);
   List<TypeC> c = dataC.getDataList(id);
   a.getC().addAll(c);
   
   return a;
}
```

DataB & DataC both extends abstract class DataDb and looks like:

```
class DataB exstends DataDb<DataB>{
   public PreparedStatment getSqlStatement(){
      return ...
   }
   public List<TypeB> transformToObject(){
      return ...
   }
}
```

Class DataDb looks like:

```
public abstact class DbData<T>{
   public T getData(String id){
      List<T> obj = collectData(id);
      return obj.isEmpty() ? null : obj.get(0);
   }
   public List<T> getDataList(String id){
      return collectData(id);
   }
   public List<T> collectData(String id){
      ...
      stmt = getSqlStatment();
      ...
      return transformToObject();
   }
  abstract PreparedStatemnet getSqlStatement();
  abstract List<T> transformToObject();
}
```

I have tried to do the test and mock but get an Exception.
It looks like my mocking of getData() and getDataList() does not work, and the actual methods in DataDb is called.

My test

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class DataTest {
   @Mock private Connection c;
   @Mock private DataB dataB;
   @Mock private DataC dataC;

   @Test
   void TestTypeA(){
      when(dataB.getData("123")).thenReturn(new TypeB());
      List<TypeC> cL = new ArrayList<>();
      cL.add(new TypeC);
      when(dataC.getDataList("123")).thenReturn(cL);

      TypeA a = collectData(c, "123");
      assertThat(a.getId(), is(equlaTo("123")));
      ...
   }
```

I have also unsuccessfully tried to mock DataDb:

```
@Mock private DataDb dataDb;
...
when(dataDb.getData("123")).thenReturn(new TypeB());
```

I have found some examples that mock explicit calls to super-methods, by using **spy** but I dont get that to work either. Gets the same exception when the "real" code calls the DB.

```
DataDb spy = Mockito.spy(new DataDb(){@Override PreparedStatement getSqlStatment(){ return null; } @Override List transformToObject(){ return null; } });
Mockito.doReturn(new TypeB()).when(spy).getData("123");
```

Comment: You create new instances of `DataA` and `DataB` in your method under test. Thus, the mocks are not used at all.

Comment: Ok, so how should I do?

Comment: Is it not possible to test?
Should I redesign the classes and use them some other way?

Comment: Your test only contains mocks, no real classes. Your production code is not tested. At the same time, your production code is creating new instances and doesn't use the mocks available in the test. Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968)

Comment: So it is not possible to mock?