# Not able to mock Logger

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, logging, mockito, slf4j

I'm trying to mock the logger provided by @Slf4j for one of my unit tests. But I am unable to do it.

Below are the code samples I am using.

Code for my service

```
package com.someorg;

import jakarta.mail.MessagingException;
import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Set;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class EmailNotificationService implements NotificationService {

    private final JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${spring.mail.from}")
    private String from;

    public void send(String content, String subject, Set<String> receivers){
        // Sends HTML email to Set of receivers
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try{
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
            messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            messageHelper.setText(content,true);
            messageHelper.setTo(receivers.toArray(new String[0]));
            messageHelper.setFrom(from);
            javaMailSender.send(message);
        }catch(MessagingException | RuntimeException e){
            log.warn("Error while sending email notification with subject %s".formatted(subject),e);
        }
    }
}
```

My test file

```
package com.someorg;

import jakarta.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSendException;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doThrow;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;


@SpringBootTest(classes = {EmailNotificationService.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.mail.from=somemail@example.com"})
class EmailNotificationServiceTest {

    @MockBean
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    @Mock
    private MimeMessage mimeMessage;
    @Mock
    Logger logger;
    @Autowired
    private EmailNotificationService emailNotificationService;
    private static final String CONTENT = "Test content";
    private static final String SUBJECT = "Test subject";
    private static final Set<String> RECEIVERS = Collections.singleton("test@example.com");

  
    @Test
    void testSendWithException(){
        // Arrange
        when(javaMailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        doThrow(new MailSendException("Simulated exception")).when(javaMailSender).send(mimeMessage);
        // Act
        emailNotificationService.send(CONTENT, SUBJECT, RECEIVERS);
        // Assert
        verify(javaMailSender).send(any(MimeMessage.class));
        verify(logger).warn(any(String.class), any(MailSendException.class));
    }
}
```

My email notification service is not mocking the logger provided by Logger in the test file. And I am getting the error as[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgfZV.png)

I tried different things by removing @Autowired and other different things, but it does not work.

Comment: And why should it? You create a mock and do nothing with it? You aren't injecting it to the `EmailNotificationService`, which you should do using the `TestReflectionUtils`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test (but not a dupe since this question adds Spring Boot to the mix)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the Captor, something like:

```
@Captor
protected ArgumentCaptor<Logger> logger;
```

Also to assert that an error is being thrown, maybe you can do something like

```
Assertions.assertThrows(MailSendException.class, () -> emailNotificationService.send(CONTENT, SUBJECT, RECEIVERS));
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking the logger in a class annotated with Lombok @Slf4j can be tricky because the logger is generated during the compile time and is not easily accessible for mocking purposes in tests. The logger is a static field in the class, which adds additional complexity of mocking it.

I can try to use the following library:
https://www.simplify4u.org/slf4j-mock/

Here is an example:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Example {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Example.class);

    public void methodWithLogInfo(String message) {
        LOGGER.info(message);
    }
}
```

then you can do the following if you are using Junit5:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class JUnit5ExampleTest {

    private static final String INFO_TEST_MESSAGE = "info log test message from JUnit5";

    @Mock
    Logger logger;

    @InjectMocks
    Example sut;

    @Test
    void logInfoShouldBeLogged() {

        // when
        sut.methodWithLogInfo(INFO_TEST_MESSAGE);

        // then
        Mockito.verify(logger).info(INFO_TEST_MESSAGE);
        Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(logger);
    }

}
```

You can find all the examples in the documentation.

Another option could be creating a custom appender that keeps logs in memory.

Comment: How is the library used? Your example code does not contain anything that looks like it would replace the logger of the class

Comment: I took this example from the official website of this library https://www.simplify4u.org/slf4j-mock/. I am not sure what exactly you do not understand, in my opinion, the example very clearly explains how to use the library. It's really easy to use once you add this library to your classpath.