# Mockito does not mocks fields which results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, mockito

When I am trying to mock the field serviceTwo to return some test data it is resulting in null pointer exception.
However mockito is mocking for serviceOne field as it should.

```
//interface
public interface MyInterface {
  void methodToBeTested();
}

//abstract class
public abstract class MyAbstarctClass {
  public static String fieldInAbstarctClass = "fieldinAbstarctclass";
} 

//actual class to be tested
public class ClassToBeTested extends MyAbstarctClass implements MyInterface {
  
  ServiceOne serviceOne;

  @Autowired
  ServiceTwo serviceTwo;

  @Autowired
  public ClassToBeTested(ServiceOne serviceOne){
    this.serviceOne = serviceOne;
  }
  
  public void methodToBeTested() {
    System.ou.println("print something..");
    String getJobName = serviceTwo.getJobName(); 
    // above line throws NullPointerException for the field  serviceTwo while testing.
  }
}

//Testerclass for junit testing 
public class Tester {

  @InjectMocks
  ClassToBeTested classToBeTested;

  @Mock
  ServiceOne serviceOne;

  @Mock
  ServiceTwo serviceTwo;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    classToBeTested = new ClassToBeTested(serviceOne);
  }

  @Test
  void methodToBeTestedTest() {
    when(serviceTwo.getJobName()).thenReturn("jobName");
    classToBeTested.methodToBeTested();
  }
}
```

I am using junit 5.8.2 with mockito 4.5.1

Has anyone come across such scenario?

Comment: I suggest not mixing constructor and field injection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) especially the corollary: (Mis-)using @InjectMocks section. Your `classToBeTested` doesn't get the mocks injected, because it is a separate, new instance independent of the one assigned (with dependencies injected) by Mockito during the `openMocks(this)` call.

Comment: And you really shouldn't be mixing field and constructor injection. Field injection is already bad as it is, but mixing it with other forms of injection is definitely worse.