# Login test always returns empty Optional (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mockito, assertj

i´m making a test for a very simple service login method, but I always get an empty Optional, when i should recieve an object. I´ve tried eevery part of the test, the "when"s are working as expected, it´s only the call to the loginUser method that returns an empty Optional. If i make a request through postman, it works just fine! i´m out of ideas as to what´s going on, does anyone have any clue?

The test:

```
  @Test
  public void testIfUserLogsIn() {
    LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO("test@test.com", "password");

    User testUser = new User(1L, "testname", "testlastname", "test@test.com", "password", USER, 
1111111111L, "testAdress", "testCity");
    when(this.userRepositoryTest.findByEmail(loginDTO.getEmail()))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(testUser));
    when(this.passwordEncoder.matches(loginDTO.getPassword(), testUser.getPassword())).thenReturn(true);

    Optional<User> result = this.userServiceTest.loginUser(loginDTO);

    assertThat(result).isPresent();
  }
```

The loginUser method in my userService:

```
  public Optional<User> loginUser(LoginDTO loginDTO) {
    Optional<User> doesUserExists = this.userRepository.findByEmail(loginDTO.getEmail());
    if (doesUserExists.isPresent()) {
      if (passwordEncoder.matches(loginDTO.getPassword(), doesUserExists.get().getPassword())) {
        return doesUserExists;
      }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
  }
```

Here are the Mocks:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserServiceTest {

  @Mock
  private UserService userServiceTest;
  @Mock
  private UserRepository userRepositoryTest;
  @InjectMocks
  private UserController userController;
  @Mock
  private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

Comment: Does your userRepository have any users inside? Might make sense that during your tests it is empty.

Comment: Show us how you create the mocks and inject them to object under test

Comment: Where do you create `userRepository`, where do you create `userServiceTest` and how do you make sure that the user repository is injected into the service? Likely the problem is https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968

Comment: Thanks for the replies, i´ve edited the post to show the userRepositoryTest and userServiceTest

Comment: if you are mocking the UserRepository and the UserService, then where is the user data coming from? It would definitely be empty unless you load some default data

Answer (score 0):

Your UserService is mocked:

```
@Mock
private UserService userServiceTest;
```

That means its real implementation will *not* be called. The mock will only do what you tell it to do – and you didn't tell it to do anything. So what happens? Mockito sets up the mock to return the default values for each respective return type (0 for numbers, false for boolean, empty collections for collections, absent optionals for optionsal, and null for strings and anything else).

If you want to exercise UserService in your test, you must not mock it, but use the actual implementation of it. Either `new` it up manually or have `@InjectMocks` create an instance of it and pass the other mocks.