# Why am I testing apache httpClient wrong?

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I have a custom HttpClient that utilizes CloseableHttpClient from Apache.

```
public class CustomHttpClientImpl implements CustomHttpClient {
    private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    public CustomHttpClientImpl() {
        this.httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Override
    public CloseableHttpResponse executePost(HttpPost request) throws Exception {
        return httpClient.execute(request);
    }
}
```

Then I have a unit test like this

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class CustomHttpClientImplTest {
    @Mock
    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
    @Mock
    private CloseableHttpResponse mockGetMethod;
    @InjectMocks
    private CustomHttpClientImpl customHttpClient;

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        HttpPost mockHttpPost = new HttpPost("http://example.com");
        CloseableHttpResponse mockResponse = Mockito.mock(CloseableHttpResponse.class);
//        when(httpClient.execute(mockHttpPost)).thenReturn(mockResponse);
        CloseableHttpResponse result = customHttpClient.executePost(mockHttpPost);
        assertNotNull(result);

    }
}
```

If I comment mocking of httpClient call then it's not a unit test, but If I do mock it, it says that this is an unnecessary stubbing.

I tried all other topics on Stackoverflow but they don't have the solution that other author's were looking for

Comment: How do you expect the mock `httpClient` to be used by `customHttpClient` when it initializes it using `this.httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();`? You should be passing it as a constructor argument.

Comment: damn, I'm so blind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test)