# HttpResponse mock is not working in Junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to junit for for below java method. I have correctly mocked CloseableHttpClient and CloseableHttpResponse but still I am getting null when my junit calls HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request); I am getting response null value. Am I missing anything ?

```
private String getEndPointResponse() {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder
            .create()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(prod.httpTimeout() * 1000)
                .build())
            .build();

        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("www.testendpoint");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            LOGGER.info("Response status: {}", statusCode);

            if (statusCode == 200) {
                LOGGER.info("Successfully retrieved data from: {}", url);
                return IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Junit

```
@AemTest
class ContnetTileTest {

    @Mock
    private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

    private AemContext context = new AemContext();

    @Mock
    private CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse;

    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws ProviderException {
        context.load().json("/com/contentTile-page.json",
            "/content/contentTile");
        context.create().resource("/content/jcr:content");

        context.registerService(CloseableHttpResponse.class, httpResponse);
        context.registerService(CloseableHttpClient.class, httpClient);


        provider = context.registerInjectActivateService(new ContnetTile());

    }


    @Test
    public void testContnetTile() throws Exception {
    
        when(httpClient.execute(any(HttpGet.class))).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(httpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mock(StatusLine.class));
        when(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()).thenReturn(200);

        //assertTrue(properties.containsKey("conTile"), "content prop");


    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test) – your method isn't using your mock

Comment: cont'd. but it is creating a new, independent, non-mocked instance with `HttpClientBuilder.create()...build()` and using that