# How to Mock HttpResponse

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I am writing the test case for a method where I am getting

`Cannot invoke “com.http.HttpResponse.getStatusCode()" because "response" is null`

I have this code

```
Package …


/* other import */


import com.company.app.http.HttpClient;
import com.company.app.http.HttpResponse;


public class DashboardService {



private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
  private final AccountMapper accountMapper;
  private final UserService userservice;
  private final HttpClient httpClient;




private Dashboard createDashboard(Req req, Dashboard db) throws SomeException {
  User user = userService.findByName(req.getId());

  HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.post(User.getUrl() + "/user", getHeaders(),
      Req, new TypeReference<>() {
      });
  if (response.getStatusCode() <= HttpStatus.SC_MULTIPLE_CHOICES) { // here is the error
    return db;
  } else {
    throw new SomeException(response.getStatusMessage() + ": " + response.getResponseText());
  }
}
```

What I am trying to mock in my test case is

```
 HttpResponse<String> mockedResponse = mock(new TypeToken<HttpResponse<String>>() {}.getRawType());
 when(httpClient.post(anyString(), anyList(), any(), any(TypeReference.class))).thenReturn(mockedResponse);
```

For additional Info this is  httpclient.post

```
@Log4j2
@Component
public class HttpClient {
  @Autowired
  public HttpClient() {

  }

public <T> HttpResponse<T> post(String url, List<Header> httpHeaders, Object data,
                                TypeReference<T> typeReference)
        throws IdentityException {
  CloseableHttpClient client = getClient();
  try {
       HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(url);
    Header[] itemsArray = new Header[httpHeaders.size()];
    itemsArray = httpHeaders.toArray(itemsArray);
    postRequest.setHeaders(itemsArray);
    postRequest.setEntity(prepareBody(data));
    org.apache.http.HttpResponse res;
    res = client.execute(postRequest);
    return new HttpResponse<>(res, typeReference);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    throw new IdentityException(e);
  } finally {
    if (client != null) {
      closeConnection(client);
    }
  }
}
  public synchronized CloseableHttpClient getClient() {
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
        .setSocketTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000)
        .setConnectionRequestTimeout(60 * 1000)
        .setConnectTimeout(2 * 60 * 1000)
        .build();
return HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
}
  }
```

HttpResponse

```
public HttpResponse(org.apache.http.HttpResponse response, TypeReference<T> typeReference)
    throws IOException {
  this.statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
  this.statusMessage = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
  if (response.getEntity() != null)
    this.responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
  log.info("Http Response details: Code - " + statusCode + ", Message - " + statusMessage);
  log.info("Response entityString: " + StringUtils.abbreviate(responseText, 500));
  setParsedResponse(typeReference);
}
```

What I am trying is also not working. Can anyone suggest me what should I try to Mock this. So that I can get off from response is null error and can proceed further.

Comment: you don't mock the response, you mock the service call that returns the response, and make sure it returns a pre-defined response which meets your requirements

Comment: @Stultuske I am getting response as null (mentioned in question) but with same data I am able to pass in normal flow. So waht could be an issue, what should I change in test class.

Comment: mock the service call. Just because your actual flow returns a valid response, doesn't mean your testing environment uses the exact same context/path/..., so it doesn't mean it will.

Comment: How do you pass `httpClient` to service under test?

Comment: Where does `httpClient` in your service come from (is it a mock object)? Please show the complete test including setup. And show the part of your service that gets the `httpClient` injected ([Why are my mocked methods not called when executing a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968))

Comment: @knittl I have `httpClient` and `httpResponse` classes which i am using at service layer like `private final HttpClient httpClient;`. i have updated in question as well.

Comment: @David you have not shown your service obtains a reference to the http client. What does `getClient()` do?

Comment: @knittl I have updated the question with Service and httpClient class

Comment: @David your example is incomplete: you never assign the `private final HttpClient httpClient` field. Your code does not compile. How is `HttpClients.custom()` implemented? Please provide a [mre].