How can I mock the result of a third-party builder so I can test my Java class?
I have a simple Java Spring Boot application to send push notifications to Android and iOS apps. There is a service class that sends the push notifications using a pusher class. The pusher class is an interface with connect, sendNotification and disconnect methods, there is an Android implementation and an iOS implementation. The service uses the correct instance when sending a notification.
The connect method creates a connection by building a client using a builder from an external library. The client is then set in a private global variable so it can be used later to send push notifications.
I want to write unit tests for the service and for both the pusher implementations. However, I don't want to connect with the actual push notification servers of Google and Apple. How can I mock the client created by the builder? I feel that the current design of the classes isn't very testable, how do I improve the testability of my classes?
public class Service {
    public void sendNotification(String notification, DeviceOS deviceOS) {
        Pusher androidPusher = new AndroidPusher();
        Pusher iOSPusher = new IOSPusher();

        switch(deviceOS) {
            case DeviceOS.ANDROID:
                androidPusher.connect();
                androidPusher.sendNotification(notification);
                androidPusher.disconnect();
                break;
            case DeviceOS.IOS:
                IOSPusher.connect();
                IOSPusher.sendNotification(notification);
                IOSPusher.disconnect();
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class IOSPusher() implements Pusher {
    private Client client;

    public void connect() {
        if (client != null) {
            return; // Already connected
        }
        client = ClientBuilder()
          .setServer("server.name")
          .setCredentials(new File("/cred"), "password")
          .build();
    }

    public void sendNotification(String notification) {
        PushNotification pushNotification = new PushNotification(notification);
        client.sendNotification(pushNotification);
        // Check the client response and do some bookkeeping based on the response.
    }

    public void disconnect() {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
}

Edit
Updated code example based on the responses, and by reducing the abstraction I originally used in my examples to keep it simple, which likely omitted important details.
@Service
public class Service {

    private final MessageDao messageDao;

    public Service(MessageDao messageDao) {
        this.messageDao = messageDao;
    }

    // This method is run periodically
    @Scheduled
    public void sendNotifications() {
        List<QueuedMessage> queuedMessages = messageDao.getNewMessages();

        Pusher androidPusher = null;
        Pusher iOSPusher = null;

        for (QueuedMessage message : queuedMessages) {
            switch (message.getDeviceOS()) {
                case DeviceOS.ANDROID:
                    if (androidPusher == null) {
                        androidPusher = new AndroidPusher();
                    }
                    sendPushNotification(androidPusher, message);
                    break;
                case DeviceOS.IOS:
                    if (iOSPusher == null) {
                        iOSPusher = new IOSPusher();
                    }
                    sendPushNotification(iOSPusher, message);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendPushNotification(Pusher pusher, QueuedMessage message) {
        pusher.connect();
        pusher.sendNotification(message.getMessage());
        pusher.disconnect();
    }
}

The application tends to run for long periods at a time, so the pushers are created when they are needed for the first time and then reused instead of being recreated each time a notification is being sent. That is the reason to have an androidPusher and iOSPusher variable and not a single pusher variable that gets instantiated with the correct instance.
Closing and reopening the connection to the Google and Apple notification servers is likely not optimal (at least not according to the third-party library used to connect to the Apple Notification Server), however I'd first like to get to a state of good test coverage before changing other parts of the implementation.

I would advice to refactor the code. First of, why are both pushers loaded, even if only one can be used at any given point in time? So I would replace the two fields androidPusher and IOSPusher with a single Pusher field. Next, I would apply inversion of control and proivde a constructor that expect some Pusher. The final, optional step I might consider taking would be to  provide ano-args constructor that does the switching. This way, we can call the injection constructor for testing and the no-args constructor in the production code.

Not a dupe, but still shows a solution to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968

@Pieter You can mock local instances - Junit local object mock. However, I strongly advise against it in your case. Your code has far too many problems, refactor it, and while at it refactor in a way to make it testable.

There are a few issues with your code:

You're creating a new AndroidPusher and a new IOSPusher every single time you want to send a notification
you're always ignoring one of the two instances, which makes it pretty pointless to have both of them at the same time
both cases execute the exact same code
what if you need more DeviceOS in the future? Would you add another instance and another piece of code for each device?
The Pusher instances only exist locally, that means your method is not testable at all

So, what to do? Both your AndroidPusher and IOSPusher implement the Pusher interface, so use that fact to make your code more generic and remove the tight coupling inside your method.
I'd suggest doing something like this:
public void sendNotification(String notification, Pusher pusher) {
    pusher.connect();
    pusher.sendNotification(notification);
    pusher.disconnect();
}

With this approach you remove the need to know which kind of Pusher implementations you have. You can then determine what implementation you actually need from the outside (based on the DeviceOS enum, for example). Also, you've added a way to make your method testable.
Afterwards, you can inject a mocked version of a Pusher into your method when testing. For example:
@Test
public void test() {
    Pusher mockPusher = Mockito.mock(Pusher.class);
    // add your mocked behavior here

    systemUnderTest.sendNotification("Test Notification", mockPusher);

    // add your asserts here
}

