How to Mock WebClient created inside service class constructor
How can I mock webClient in my unit test for the class below
@Service
public class Service {
  private final WebClient webClient;
  public Service(String baseUrl) {
    this.webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
  }
  public User getUser() { webClient.get().bodyToMono(User.class).block(); }
}


ReflectionTestUtils works, is there a better way?
No constructor injection of WebClient Service(WebClient webClient)

Any solutions?

Why are you not able to provide the client through constructor injection?

Related, but not a dupe. The presented solution still applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test

For classes that you can't inject directly, you can wrap the WebClient into a wrapper service:
@Service
public class YourWrapperWebClient{
    private final WebClient webClient;
    // constructor..
    YourWrapperWebClient(){
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()....
    }
    // methods you care about that return the same thing as the WebClient's
}

Now you can inject YourWrapperWebClient into your service classes. This way you can mock YourWrapperWebClient. It indirectly mocks the WebClient.
