java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: From address must not be null
I have a project with Java 17 and Spring 3. In my pom.xml the Test extensions are the following:

junit-jupiter: version 5.10.1.
mockito-core: version 5.8.0.
mockito-junit-jupiter: version 5.8.0

I have the following class:
@Service
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Value("${mail.senderUsername}")
    private String mailSenderUsername;

    @Override
    public void sendMailConfirmationToken(MailSimpleRequest mailRequest) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");

        message.setFrom(mailSenderUsername);
        message.setTo(mailRequest.toUsers());
        message.setSubject(mailRequest.subject());
        message.setText("<div><p>Message</p></div>", true);

        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }

}

I am doing the following test:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MailServiceImplTest {

    @Mock
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Mock
    private MimeMessage mimeMessage;

    @Mock
    private MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper;

    private final MailSimpleRequest mailRequest = Data.givenMailRequest();

    @InjectMocks
    private MailServiceImpl mailService;

    @Test
    void sendMailConfirmationToken() throws MessagingException {
        when(mailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);

        mailService.sendMailConfirmationToken(mailRequest);

        verify(mailSender).send(any(MimeMessage.class));
    }
}

When I verify the test, it gives me the following error:
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: From address must not be null

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:172)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper.setFrom(MimeMessageHelper.java:571)
    at ms.mailsender.service.impl.MailServiceImpl.sendMailConfirmationToken(MailServiceImpl.java:40)
    at ms.mailsender.service.impl.MailServiceImplTest.sendMailConfirmationToken(MailServiceImplTest.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

¿Does anyone know how it can be solved??

The error you're encountering is related to the
setFrom
method of the
MimeMessageHelper
class. The error message
"From address must not be null"
indicates that the
mailSenderUsername
value is null when the
setFrom
method is called.
In your test case, you're not mocking the
@Value("${mail.senderUsername}")
field, which means that it will have its default value of null. To fix this issue, you can either:

MimeMessageHelper is created in your method, the @Mock mimeMessageHelper field is ignored (and it is not even stubbed in your test). mailSenderUsername is never assigned in your test and defaults to null. Read more on why using new and @Mock don't work together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test

    In this approach, you mock the MailServiceImpl.class itself and use the 
    when method to stub the  getMailSenderUsername method to return a valid 
    email address.
    
    Use the 
    @TestPropertySource
     annotation:
    
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    @TestPropertySource(properties = "mail.senderUsername=sender@example.com")
    class MailServiceImplTest {
        // ...
    }
    
    
  his annotation allows you to set the mail.senderUsername
  property value for the test case, ensuring that it's not null when 
 the  MailServiceImpl class is instantiated.Both approaches should 
  resolve the "From address must not be null" error by providing a 
  non-null value for the  mailSenderUsername field.


The error you're encountering is related to the setFrom method of the MimeMessageHelper class. The error message "From address must not be null" indicates that the mailSenderUsername value is null when the setFrom method is called. In your test case, you're not mocking the @Value("${mail.senderUsername}") field, which means that it will have its default value of null. To fix this issue, you can either: –

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MailServiceImplTest {
    // ...

    @Mock
    private MailServiceImpl mailServiceImplMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private MailServiceImpl mailService;

    @Test
    void sendMailConfirmationToken() throws MessagingException {
        when(mailSender.createMimeMessage()).thenReturn(mimeMessage);
        when(mailServiceImplMock.getMailSenderUsername()).thenReturn("sender@example.com");

        mailService.sendMailConfirmationToken(mailRequest);

        verify(mailSender).send(any(MimeMessage.class));
    }
}

