Mocking an Object that uses casting in Mockito
I am working on a Java project where I need to write unit tests with testng for a class that has a method similar to the following:
public boolean isValidCode(String code) {
    GenericService service = null;
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean proxy = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    proxy.setServiceClass(GenericService.class);
    proxy.setServiceName(new QName(this.genericServiceName));
    // More proxy configurations
    service = (GenericService) proxy.create();
    return service.exists(new CodeInput(code));
}

The isValidCode method calls a method "exists" from a service interface GenericService. The exists method in GenericService is responsible for checking the existence of a code.
I'd like to be able to mock the "service" object that's created and specifically, mock the "exists" method. However, I'm having difficulty mocking this object since it's a JaxWsProxyFactoryBean object that's being cast as a GenericService object.
Here's the interface for GenericService:
@WebService(name = "GenericService", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/GenericService")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@BindingType(javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface GenericService {

    @WebMethod(operationName = "GenericExists", action = "http://example.com/GenericService/GenericExists")
    @WebResult(name = "GenericExistsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/GenericService", partName = "response")
    public GenericExists exists(
        @WebParam(name = "GenericExistsRequest", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/GenericService", partName = "CodeInput")
        CodeInput codeInput);
}

I tried mocking the GenericService interface as follows:
GenericService serviceMock = mock(GenericService.class)
when(serviceMock.exists(any(CodeInput.class))).thenReturn(true);

However, this doesn't seem to work since when I execute isValidCode in my tests it still calls the actual WebMethod "exists". I'm not sure if this is because of the casting of the JaxWsProxyBeanFactory object.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test – why do you expect ServiceMock to be available in your method? You never pass nor inject it.

First, your mock created with mock(GenericService.class) will not be available per default.
It will create a dummy object that you need to pass to your class under test in order to use it.
In your particular use case, you want to return your serviceMock when JaxWsProxyFactoryBean#proxy was called. Since your JaxWsProxyFactoryBean is also created during the test, you can replace it with an mock during the creation of the object via mockConstruction. In the mockConstruction, you can give your proxy method a new behavior by returning serviceMock whenever it is called.
// create your mock object as normal
GenericService serviceMock = mock(GenericService.class);
when(serviceMock.exists(any(CodeInput.class))).thenReturn(true);

// change the construction of your JaxWsProxyFactoryBean
try (MockedConstruction<JaxWsProxyFactoryBean> mockJaxWsProxyFactoryBean = mockConstruction(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.class, (mock, context) -> {
    // return your created serviceMock when the create method is called
    when(mock.create()).thenReturn(serviceMock);
})) {
    // do your asserts
    Assertions.assertTrue(myObject.isValidCode("foo"));

}

