I cant init my webclient in a test with mockito
I'm working on a project with java spring boot 2.x and java 1.8. In my pom i got the dependencies of junit 4.13.2 and mockito 3.12.4. When i try to run my test i got the problem that my setup function is not running even with the @before annotation so webclient builder is null
@Service
public class StarshipService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    public StarshipService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("https://www.swapi.tech/api").build();
    }

    public StarshipResponse getStarships(int page, int size, String nameOrId){
        try {

            // Si nameOrId es un número, busca por ID
            if (nameOrId != null && nameOrId.matches("\\d+")) {
                return getStarshipById(nameOrId);
            }

            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://www.swapi.tech/api/starships");

            if (page != 0){
                builder.queryParam("page", page);
            }
            builder.queryParam("limit", size);
            if (nameOrId != null && !nameOrId.isEmpty()) {
                builder.queryParam("name", nameOrId);
            }

            String url = builder.toUriString();

            Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> responseMono = this.webClient.get()
                    .uri(url)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(String.class);

            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = responseMono.block();

            if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                String responseBody = responseEntity.getBody();
                if (responseBody != null && responseBody.contains("results")) {
                    return StarWarsParseService.parseStandardStarshipResponse(responseBody);
                } else if (responseBody != null && responseBody.contains("result")) {
                    return StarWarsParseService.parseSearchStarshipResponse(responseBody);
                }
            }
            return new StarshipResponse();
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
            System.err.println("Error al llamar a la API de Star Wars: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StarshipResponse();
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public StarshipResponse getStarshipById(String id) throws JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            String url = "https://www.swapi.tech/api/starships/" + id;

            Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> responseMono = this.webClient.get()
                    .uri(url)
                    .retrieve()
                    .toEntity(String.class);

            try{
                ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = responseMono.block();
                if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    return StarWarsParseService.parseIdStarshipResponse(responseEntity.getBody());
                } else {
                    System.err.println("Unexpected response or status code: " + responseEntity);
                    return new StarshipResponse();
                }
            }catch (WebClientResponseException.NotFound ex){
                System.err.println("Person with ID " + id + " not found in SWAPI");
                StarshipResponse starshipResponse = new StarshipResponse();
                starshipResponse.setResults(new ArrayList<>());
                starshipResponse.setTotal_records(0);
                starshipResponse.setTotal_pages(1);
                return starshipResponse;
            }
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al llamar a la API de Star Wars: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StarshipResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unexpected error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new StarshipResponse();
        }
    }
}

and this test with mockito and junit
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class StarshipServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Mock
    private WebClient webClient;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpec;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpec;

    @Mock
    private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

    @InjectMocks
    private StarshipService starshipService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        when(webClientBuilder.baseUrl(anyString())).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
        when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStarships() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Mock the WebClient behavior
        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
        when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>("{\"results\": []}", HttpStatus.OK)));

        // Call the method to test
        StarshipResponse response = starshipService.getStarships(1, 10, null);

        // Assert the response
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(0, response.getResults().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStarshipById() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Mock the WebClient behavior
        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
        when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>("{\"result\": {\"properties\": {\"name\": \"Millennium Falcon\"}}}", HttpStatus.OK)));

        // Call the method to test
        StarshipResponse response = starshipService.getStarshipById("10");

        // Assert the response
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals("Millennium Falcon", response.getResults().get(0).getName());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetStarshipByIdNotFound() throws JsonProcessingException {
        // Mock the WebClient behavior for 404 Not Found
        when(webClient.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriSpec);
        when(requestHeadersUriSpec.uri(anyString())).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpec);
        when(requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpec);
        when(responseSpec.toEntity(String.class)).thenReturn(Mono.error(new WebClientResponseException(404, "Not Found", null, null, null)));

        // Call the method to test
        StarshipResponse response = starshipService.getStarshipById("0");

        // Assert the response
        assertNotNull(response);
        assertEquals(0, response.getTotal_records());
    }
}

but when i try to run the test i got this error
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException:
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'starshipService' of type 'class com.example.conexatest.conexatest.service.StarshipService'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.build()" because the return value of "org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient$Builder.baseUrl(String)" is null
when i put a breakpoint in the setup function i cant reach it when i'm debugging
I have fixed some thing and now i can enter the setup function but the webClientBuilder is null and when i call the when() function the program crash. In my project i got a config like this
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
}

and the service is consuming this like this:
private final WebClient webClient;

    @Autowired
    public StarshipService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("https://www.swapi.tech/api").build();
}


Post full text of error.

Why do you mix @SpringBootTest and @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)? Those two shouldn't be mixed. Since you are not using any beans, get rid of @SpringBootTest – it's useless to start the application context if you are not going to use it.

Furthermore, you already have @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) (initializes and injects mocks) and then MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); (initializes new mocks and injects them again, overwriting the existing mocks). This is yet another variant of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74027324/112968 (stubbing the calls on the wrong mock instance)

And why do you use an EOL Java version, and a likely EOL Spring version? If possible, upgrade your runtime and your libraries.

Your constructor builds a WebClient from the passed webClientBuilder, but at this point in time, no methods have been stubbed on the builder, so baseUrl(…) will simply return the default value for the return type (i.e. null).
@Autowired
public StarshipService(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
    this.webClient = webClientBuilder.baseUrl("https://www.swapi.tech/api").build();
}

First, the Mockito Runner will initialize the Mocks and assign them to the fields and only then will the setup method be executed.
In your case, you need to manually construct your service instance and pass the stubbed mock objects:
@Mock
private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec;

private StarshipService starshipService; // assigned in setup

@Before
public void setUp() {
    when(webClientBuilder.baseUrl(anyString())).thenReturn(webClientBuilder);
    when(webClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(webClient);

    this.starshipService = new StarshipService(webClientBuilder);
}

You also want to get rid of all the unnecessary annotations and statements:

@SpringBootTest: You are not using any Spring beans nor Spring functionality such as autowiring, so why load the application context?
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);: You are already running the test with the MockitoJUnitRunner, so initMocks will initialize new mock instances and reassign all fields (which already have different (mock) instances assigned via @Mock and @InjectMocks).

