Mockito mock not invoked
I have some java base class that has inside 1 method:

public class SB {

    @SneakyThrows
    public Document downloadHtml(String url) {
        return Jsoup.connect(url)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/127.0.2651.98")
                .get();
    }
}

I have also another class that extends SB and implements some interface:
public class TScrapperProvider extends SB implements Scrapper {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TelemagazynScrapperProvider.class);


    @Override
    public List<Channel> getAllChannels() {
        Document doc = downloadHtml("URL");
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public List<TVShow> getChannelScheduleForDate(LocalDate date, Channel channel) {
        Document doc = downloadHtml("URL");
        ....
    }
}


And then I have a unit tests class where I would like to test both of methods from TScrapperProvider and in order to do it I want to mock downloadHtml method from SB:
    @Test
    public void testGetAllChannels() {
        SB sBase = mock(SB.class);
        when(sBase.downloadHtml("https://example.html")).thenReturn(createMockChannelsPage());

        Scrapper scrapper = new TScrapperProvider();
        List<Channel> channels = scrapper.getAllChannels();
        verify(sBase, times(1)).downloadHtml("https://example.html");
        assertEquals(createExpectedChannels(), channels);
    }

Unfortuantely verify fails with Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock. and I see in results that results are from real page and not from my mock.
How can I call mock instead of real downloadHtml method?

sBase is never injected into the code you are testing. The composition of your code makes it hard to test with verify, since you are hoping to verify an internal call withing TScrapperProvider. You could solve this by extracting downloadHtml to a separate class and mock that. Otherwise you would have to verify the static methods of Jsoup (though I would not recommend attempting to mock static methods, as that's quite complex).

Hi. I wouldn't like to mock static Jsoup method. Actually I have moved downloadHtml method  from SB to some utility class and then mocked this utility class but the outcome is the same - mock not called

You cannot create a mock instance of the base class and expect all child instances to magically use the stubbed calls. See first paragraph of "Problem Overview" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74027325/112968 – also, why are you mocking the thing you are testing?

You need to use spy.
    @Test
    public void testGetAllChannels() {
        TScrapperProvider scrapper = spy(new TScrapperProvider());
        doReturn(createMockChannelsPage()).when(scrapper).downloadHtml("https://example.html"));
        List<Channel> channels = scrapper.getAllChannels();
        verify(scrapper, times(1)).downloadHtml("https://example.html");
        assertEquals(createExpectedChannels(), channels);
    }

spy is dangerous method, I suggest to avoid it. It is better to redesign your class. Maybe split into two independent classes and inject one into another.

When you call when(mock.call()).thenXxx(...) on a spy, the code inside when is actually called. It's often better to use doXxx(...).when(mock).call() as that will not invoke the actual call() implementation of the spy.

@RobSpoor fair enough. Fixed my answer.
