Junit test case is not working as expected

tried almost everything still getting null in the response

Below is the test case
@Test
public void testValidateMemberData_Success() throws Exception {
    MemberValidationRequest memberRequest = new MemberValidationRequest();
    memberRequest.setCorelationIdentifier("123");

    MemberDataValidationResponse mockResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
    mockResponse.setStatus("200");

    HttpHeaders headers = SelfServiceValidation.populateTokenHeaders();
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new JSONObject(memberRequest).toString(), headers);
    
    when(SelfServiceValidation.getRestTemplate()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
    
    when(restTemplate.exchange(any(), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(MemberDataValidationResponse.class)))
            .thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(mockResponse));
    MemberDataValidationResponse response = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
    
     try (MockedStatic<SelfServiceDaoHelper> mockStatic = mockStatic(SelfServiceDaoHelper.class)) {
         
         mockStatic.when(() ->SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(1);
                 
     assertEquals(1, SelfServiceDaoHelper.auditApiRequestData(new MapSqlParameterSource()));
     MemberDataValidationResponse result = SelfServiceValidation.validateMemberData(memberRequest);
     response = result;
     
     };
    
    assertNotNull(response);
    assertEquals("200", response.getStatus());
}

below are the methods for it.
public static MemberDataValidationResponse validateMemberData(MemberValidationRequest memberValidationRequest)
        throws Exception {
    MemberDataValidationResponse memberValidateResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse();
    try {
        if (isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(selfServicePortalURL)) {
            String corelationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            String spanId = corelationId + SelfServicePortalConstants.MEMBER_VALIDATION_CODE;
            HttpHeaders headers = populateTokenHeaders();
            RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate();
            String validateMemberAPI = selfServicePortalURL + Endpoints.MEMBER_VALIDATION;
            log.info("Self Service Portal API URL :{}", validateMemberAPI);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(memberValidationRequest);
            String requestBody = jsonObj.toString();
            HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, headers);
            processRequestAudit(memberValidationRequest, corelationId, spanId, ipAddress.toString(),
                    "Member Validation", "Claim Submission");
            UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(validateMemberAPI);
            ResponseEntity<MemberDataValidationResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                    builder.buildAndExpand().toUri(), HttpMethod.POST, request, MemberDataValidationResponse.class);
            memberValidateResponse = (MemberDataValidationResponse) response.getBody();
            processResponseAudit(memberValidateResponse, "", spanId, corelationId);
        } else {
            log.info(SELF_SERVICE_PORTAL_UNAVAILABLE_MESSAGE);
        }
    } catch (Exception cause) {
        throw new RuntimeException(cause);
    }
    return memberValidateResponse;
}


public static RestTemplate getRestTemplate (){
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate;
}


null in which line?

assertNotNull(response);  response in null..

when(SelfServiceValidation.getRestTemplate()).thenReturn(restTemplate); you cannot stub static method calls. This should already complain in this line. I'm almost inclined to say this is a dupe of your previous question. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test in full?

Any directions on this .. tried powermockito but it is also not working

response is null  since its declare inside method and hence everytime creating instance. when test run, it create new instance which is null. Put ResponseEntity response ; outside method and try . (try mockito-inline)

The best you can do is to:

change your SelfServiceValidation methods to non-static
change SelfServiceValidation to a Spring-managed bean
inject RestTemplate to SelfServiceValidation via constructor.

Entire Spring DI revolves around this pattern. It is Spring that will create the service for you. If the service needs some dependencies you express that by injecting them.
You mentioned that you have a bizarre team structure where you write test for another team. What you should do in this case is to come back to them with a feedback that they write non-testable code, and coach them how to do it properly.
Having said that: In current shape it is possible to test your method.
You have extracted getRestTemplate so you can:

mock static only getRestTemplate and not other methods in SelfServiceValidation
this is an equivalent of overriding one method in Object-Under-Test for non-static methods
by default mockStatic stubs all static methods in a class
you can change that behaviour by using Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS

Your test will look like:
package com.example;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SelfServiceValidationTest {

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void testValidateMemberData_Success() {
        try (var valdationMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(SelfServiceValidation.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
            var  mockResponse = new MemberDataValidationResponse("123", "200");
            when(SelfServiceValidation.getRestTemplate()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
            when(restTemplate.exchange(
                    any(),
                    eq(HttpMethod.POST),
                    any(HttpEntity.class),
                    eq(MemberDataValidationResponse.class))
            ).thenReturn(ResponseEntity.ok(mockResponse));
            var memberValidationRequest = new MemberValidationRequest("123");
            var response = SelfServiceValidation.validateMemberData(memberValidationRequest);

            Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo("200");
        }
    }
}


@dhs,
Please post the logs.
In your code, you need a little bit of restructuring to make it more readable, for instance
try (MockedStatic<SelfServiceValidation> mockStaticValidation = mockStatic(SelfServiceValidation.class)) {
    mockStaticValidation.when(() -> SelfServiceValidation.isSelfServicePortalServerAvailable(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
    // Your test code here
}

Also, there is no need of:
MemberDataValidationResponse response = new MemberDataValidationResponse();

you can directly use the result variable in the assert statement.
There are a few unnecessary Mocks like:
when(SelfServiceValidation.getRestTemplate()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
getRestTemplate() is always going to return restTemplate object, hence there is no need to mock it.
