Mocked method inside lambda expression is not working
I am using the mockito but connection.prepareStatement is not getting matched and I am getting null as PreparedStatement. I have checked connection is getting mocked properly
void myMethod(){
    getJdbcTemplate().update(connection -> {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(addEmailData, new String[] { "mail_id" });
            ps.setString(++i, mailBean.getFromEmailId());

            return ps;
        }, keyHolder);
}

Below is the test case written
    void test(){
        when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString(),any(String[].class))).thenReturn(mock(PreparedStatement.class));
        when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        myClass.init(dataSource);
        // Act
        myClass.myMethod(); 
    }

Can someone please advise how to return prepareStatement so that calls on PS can be tested

Where is instance of connection  come from?

I suspect getJdbcTemplate() create other instance of connection.

Are you sure it's the PreparedStatement ps that is null, or is it the values returned by all of its methods when JdbcTemplate tries to use it?

ps is null that is confirmed

Are you using lenient stubbing? It sounds like connection.prepareStatement() is not getting mocked for some reason, and returning null instead. If you use strict stubbing, it will throw an exception saying there is no mock set up for the method and you can check why from there.

Also, in your debugger (or by adding a print statement), check the identity of the connection mock you use in your when statement, and check the identity of the connection lambda parameter. Are they the same instance?

What does getJdbcTemplate() reteurn? How does your test ensure that the lambda update is called with the stubbed connection instance from your test? You might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-is-my-class-not-calling-my-mocked-methods-in-unit-test

Thanks! all for your valuable input . I only wrote the problem specific code. Everything was fine I missed mocking the addEmaildata and rather passing null which was not matching with anyString()

In fact, when testing the myMethod() method, you have to test the PreparedStatementCreator interface implementation, which is created by the connection -> { ... } lambda expression when calling the JdbcTemplate.update() method. To do this, you must capture the argument with which this method is called, so that you can then call it with a mock Connection implementation.
For example, you can do this.
Create mock implementations of the Connection, JdbcTemplate, and PreparedStatement interfaces.
Connection connection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);

Create a captor for the PreparedStatementCreator implementation that is created in your method.
ArgumentCaptor<PreparedStatementCreator> preparedStatementCreatorCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(PreparedStatementCreator.class);

Define the behavior of a mock Connection implementation when the Connection.prepareStatement() method is called.
Mockito.when(connection.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(String[].class))).thenReturn(preparedStatement);

Execute your method with a mock JdbcTemplate implementation.
MyClass myClass = new MyClass(jdbcTemplate);
myClass.myMethod();

Make sure your method calls JdbcTemplate.update() and capture the PreparedStatementCreator implementation.
Mockito.verify(jdbcTemplate).update(preparedStatementCreatorCaptor.capture(), Mockito.any(KeyHolder.class));

Make sure that this PreparedStatementCreator implementation creates the exact PreparedStatement that your Connection returns.
Assertions.assertEquals(preparedStatement, preparedStatementCreatorCaptor.getValue().createPreparedStatement(connection));


Thank you for providing all the explanations . it should definitely be helpful for people writing test case for this kind of implementation.
