Mockito is behaving in a weird way
I was doing some testing and I can't get it right.
I was making some tests using mockito and jqwik and I wanted to assert if a method was being called exactly 5 times for that I used the function
@Property
void verifycoligions(@ForAll("ActionArbitrary") GUI.Action action, @ForAll boolean collidesUp,@ForAll boolean collidesDown, @ForAll boolean colidesright)
{
    Mockito.when(chicken.getPosition()).thenReturn(new Position(0,0));
    Mockito.when(chicken.getHeight()).thenReturn(40);
    Mockito.when(chicken.getWidth()).thenReturn(40);
    Mockito.when(chickenController.getLocation()).thenReturn(chicken);
    Mockito.when(map.collidesDown(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(collidesDown);
    Mockito.when(map.collidesRight(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(colidesright);
    Mockito.when(map.collidesUp(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn( collidesUp);
    Mockito.when(map.collidesHarmObject(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(false);
    mapController = new MapController(map,chickenController,offset);

    mapController.step(game, gui, action);

    Mockito.verify(chickenController, Mockito.times(5)).step(game,gui,action);
}

but it looks like the mockito is summing the number of interactions with the mock because when I do this it gives me an error
Wanted 5 times: -> at com.chickengame.controller.MapControllerTest.verifycoligions(MapControllerTest.java:104) But was 10 times:
at first, I thought even though my code only called it 5 times I did something wrong, so for testing I changed the number of expected interactions to 10 and then the same error appeared but a little different
Wanted 5 times: -> at com.chickengame.controller.MapControllerTest.verifycoligions(MapControllerTest.java:104) But was 5 times:
My question is, does Mockito sum up the number of interactions?
The class that I'm testing is this one
package com.chickengame.controller.game;

import com.chickengame.Game;
import com.chickengame.controller.Controller;
import com.chickengame.gui.GUI;
import com.chickengame.model.Position;
import com.chickengame.model.menus.GameEndMenu;
import com.chickengame.model.game.elements.Chicken;
import com.chickengame.model.game.map.Map;
import com.chickengame.state.menus.GameEndState;

public class MapController extends Controller<Map> {
    private final Chicken chicken;
    private final ChickenController chickenController;
    private final int adapter;

    public MapController(Map location, ChickenController chickenController, int adapter) {
        super(location);
        this.chickenController = chickenController;
        this.chicken = chickenController.getLocation();
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void step(Game game, GUI gui, GUI.Action action) {

        Position position = chicken.getPosition();

        boolean chickenOutX = (position.getX() + chicken.getWidth() <= 0);
        boolean chickenOutUp = (position.getY() + chicken.getHeight() <= 0);
        boolean chickenOutDown = (position.getY() >= 375);

        chickenOut(chickenOutX,chickenOutUp,chickenOutDown, game);

        int chickenXMin = chicken.getPosition().getX();
        int chickenXMax = chickenXMin + chicken.getWidth();
        int chickenYMin = chicken.getPosition().getY();
        int chickenYMax = chickenYMin + chicken.getHeight();

        colidesHarmObject(game, getLocation().collidesHarmObject(chickenXMin, chickenXMax, chickenYMin, chickenYMax));
        for (int i = 0; i < adapter; i++) {
            chickenXMin = chicken.getPosition().getX();
            chickenXMax = chickenXMin + chicken.getWidth();
            chickenYMin = chicken.getPosition().getY();
            chickenYMax = chickenYMin + chicken.getHeight();

            moveCamera(-1);

            boolean chickenCollidesDown = (!chicken.isInverted() && getLocation().collidesDown(chickenXMin, chickenXMax, chickenYMax));
            boolean chickenCollidesUp = (chicken.isInverted() && getLocation().collidesUp(chickenXMin, chickenXMax, chickenYMin));

            if (getLocation().collidesHarmObject(chickenXMin, chickenXMax, chickenYMin, chickenYMax)) {
                break;
            }
            colidesUpDown(chickenCollidesDown, chickenCollidesUp);
            colidesRight(chickenXMax, chickenYMin, chickenYMax);

            chickenController.step(game, gui, action);
        }
    }

    void chickenOut(boolean chickenOutX, boolean chickenOutUp, boolean chickenOutDown, Game game ){

        if(chickenOutX ||chickenOutUp ||chickenOutDown)
        {
            GameEndState endState = new GameEndState(new GameEndMenu("gameOver"));
            game.setState(endState);
        }
    }
    public void colidesHarmObject(Game game,boolean colidesharmobject)
    {
        if(colidesharmobject)
        {
            GameEndState endState = new GameEndState(new GameEndMenu("gameOver"));
            game.setState(endState);
        }
    }
    public void colidesUpDown(boolean chickenCollidesDown, boolean chickenCollidesUp)
    {
            if(chickenCollidesDown || chickenCollidesUp)
            {
                chicken.setCharge(true);
            }
            else
            {
                chickenController.moveY();
            }
    }
    public void colidesRight(int chickenXMax, int chickenYMin, int chickenYMax)
    {
            if(getLocation().collidesRight(chickenXMax,chickenYMin,chickenYMax))
            {
                chickenController.stopX();
            }
    }
    public void moveCamera(int offset)
    {
        getLocation().moveMap(offset);
    }
}


Meanwhile, if I use the inorder of Mockito, I can execute the test with no problems.

What is game, gui, and action? Are these the actual values that are passed (5 times) to your function? What is chickenController, is it a mock?

The game is my game instance, the GUI is the interface responsible for rendering my game, and Action is an enum inside the GUI that contains all possible actions. Yes, chickenController is a mock as well as game and GUI.

You must include a [mre] for your question to be answerable. That means: The full test including setup code and all relevant code of you mapController class. Showing a single loop is not sufficient (how are the dependencies wired, how is the test injecting them? etc.). Common problems with Mockito and their solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test

What do you mean by "if i use the inorder of Mockito, I can execute the test with no problems"? Are you executing more tests than this one?

I am actually executing other tests, but I don't know if it is relevant to my question.

How are you initialising your mocks?  Each mock object will count all the method calls that you make on it.  The usual way to use Mockito is to instantiate a new bunch of mock objects for every test.
