Can't write a good test for service layer in java application
I've tried to make some tests for Service layer in my java project. The test supposed to simply mock adding a new patient to database. After constantly failing, I simply gave up, and came here for seek help.
My current code for the test class is following:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PatientServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private PatientDao patientDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private PatientServiceImpl patientService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        PatientEntity patient = new PatientEntity();
        PatientTO patientTO = new PatientTO();
        patientTO.setId(1L);

        when(PatientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO)).thenReturn(patient);
        when(patientDao.save(patient)).thenReturn(patient);

        PatientTO result = patientService.save(patientTO);

        assertNotNull(result);
        verify(patientDao, times(1)).save(patient);
//        verify(PatientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO), times(1));
    }
}

Mapper
public class PatientMapper {
    public static PatientTO mapToTO(final PatientEntity patientEntity) {
        if (patientEntity == null) return null;

        final PatientTO patientTO = new PatientTO();
        patientTO.setId(patientTO.getId());
        patientTO.setFirstName(patientEntity.getFirstName());
        patientTO.setLastName(patientEntity.getLastName());
        patientTO.setTelephoneNumber(patientEntity.getTelephoneNumber());
        patientTO.setEmail(patientEntity.getEmail());
        patientTO.setPatientNumber(patientEntity.getPatientNumber());
        patientTO.setDateOfBirth(patientEntity.getDateOfBirth());
        patientTO.setDoesHaveChronicDiseases(patientEntity.getDoesHaveChronicDisease());

        return patientTO;

    }

    public static PatientEntity mapToEntity(final PatientTO patientTO) {
        if (patientTO == null) return null;

        final PatientEntity patientEntity = new PatientEntity();
        patientEntity.setId(patientTO.getId());
        patientEntity.setFirstName(patientTO.getFirstName());
        patientEntity.setLastName(patientTO.getLastName());
        patientEntity.setTelephoneNumber(patientTO.getTelephoneNumber());
        patientEntity.setEmail(patientTO.getEmail());
        patientEntity.setPatientNumber(patientTO.getPatientNumber());
        patientEntity.setDateOfBirth(patientTO.getDateOfBirth());
        patientEntity.setDoesHaveChronicDisease(patientTO.getDoesHaveChronicDiseases());

        return patientEntity;
    }
}

DAO
 public interface PatientDao extends Dao<PatientEntity, Long>  { }

DAO impl
@Repository
public class PatientDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<PatientEntity, Long> implements PatientDao{ }

Entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "PATIENT")
public class PatientEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String firstName;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String lastName;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String telephoneNumber;

private String email;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String patientNumber;

@Column(nullable = false)
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

@Column(nullable = false)
private Boolean doesHaveChronicDisease;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getTelephoneNumber() {
    return telephoneNumber;
}

public void setTelephoneNumber(String telephoneNumber) {
    this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPatientNumber() {
    return patientNumber;
}

public void setPatientNumber(String patientNumber) {
    this.patientNumber = patientNumber;
}

public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public Boolean getDoesHaveChronicDisease() {
    return doesHaveChronicDisease;
}

public void setDoesHaveChronicDisease(Boolean doesHaveChronicDisease) {
    this.doesHaveChronicDisease = doesHaveChronicDisease;
}

}
Service
public interface PatientService {
PatientTO findById(final Long ID);
PatientTO save(final PatientTO patientTO);
}

Service impl
@Service
@Transactional
public class PatientServiceImpl implements PatientService {

private final PatientDao patientDao;

@Autowired
public  PatientServiceImpl(PatientDao patientDao){
    this.patientDao = patientDao;
}

@Override
public PatientTO findById(Long ID) {
    final PatientEntity patientEntity = patientDao.findOne(ID);
    return PatientMapper.mapToTO(patientEntity);
}

@Override
public PatientTO save(PatientTO patientTO) {
    final PatientEntity patientEntity = PatientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO);
    patientDao.save(patientEntity);
    return PatientMapper.mapToTO(patientEntity);
}
}

I;ve already covered a lot of errors, but the most occuring one is:
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.

which is pointing at:
when(patientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO)).thenReturn(patient);

But I've already used it mocked, or as a concrete object. How I may improve? How I can write a test, where I can check if after deleting patient, all of his appointments were deleted too, with using cascades?

Why do you annotate with both @SpringBootTest and @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)? You must choose either and cannot use both at the same time. @RunWith is JUnit 4, can you not upgrade to JUnit 5 (even though this won't solve your immediate problem)? PatientMapper.mapToEntity looks like a static method call, yet you create a mock for the instance (but never call a non-static method on the instance)

when(patientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO)).thenReturn(patient); patientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO) is a static method call (so in fact PatientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO); note the capital P) and not a method call on the mock instance.

@knittl I did changed it, but the output is pretty much the same. I'm really out of ideas right now.

What did you change? Standard when cannot mock static method calls. @Mock does not magically make your class mocked (useful reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027324/why-are-my-mocked-methods-not-called-when-executing-a-unit-test)

@knittl I've deleted the mock of the Mapper class, and started to using it as a static (with capital P) one, and changed entity of the test class to @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class). I don't want this class to get "magically" running. I just want to get some clarification at this field, because I feel lost in research.

You must not use MockitoExtension and SpringBootTest together. Since you mock everything, I'd suggest removing SpringBootTest.

For now on, I use just @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class). Nothing else.

Which errors are left? Please [edit] your question to reflect the current state of your code.

I've just make an edit.  The error is remaining the same. I'm just make a few changes in annotations, and using static methods, as you said.

You still have when(PatientMapper.mapToEntity(patientTO)).thenReturn(patient);. PatientMapper is not a mock – to quote myself from 1 hour ago: "Standard when cannot mock static method calls"

Also, I only noticed now that you have MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); as well in your class. This must not be used together with the mockito extension, choose one and drop the other (see Corollary: (Mis-)using @InjectMocks of https://stackoverflow.com/a/74027325/112968)
